# I am trying to skip 'Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses' and directly generate the download link

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api, php-curl

The website stores a cookie with
name = "download_warning_17554090818303548941_17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe"
('17554090818303548941' This part is different for every user.)
and
value = "dYTm" (This changes after every reload.)

Once this cookie is present. Opening this
`https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=IZu5&id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe` will respond you with the download link. I am think that using curl php would do it. I already have the cookie, but don't know how to use it to open the link mentioned above to get the correct response.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe&export=download');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  // get headers too with this line
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
  $cookies = array();
  foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
      parse_str($item, $cookie);
      $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }
var_dump($cookies);
```

I use this code to get the cookies. But don't know how to use it again so that it can be use to verify the confirm code and generate the download link.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the logic but i don't have time to code :

When you first

```
GET https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=IZu5&id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can see the **response headers** includes the cookie you were talking about (`download_warning_17554090818303548941_17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe={{VALUE}}`)

In order **to verify** and download the file, you need to GET again at the same address again, but you need to programmatically change the old `confirm=IZu5` by `confirm={{VALUE}}`

```
GET https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm={{VALUE}}&id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will confirm the download and will trigger a few redirection (status 302) that will end up downloading your file

Answer (score 0):

[image]This code give me the correct download link but I still can't download it. Because access is denied.

```
<?php
  $url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe&export=download";
  $handle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, True);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($handle);
  preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
  $cookies = array();
  foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
      parse_str($item, $cookie);
      $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }
    
    $keys = array_keys($cookies);
    $values = array_values($cookies);
    $next_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=" . $values[0] . "&id=17_sIpX2amTqf2VOpLPO9IM9rDB-4vFHe";
    $res_cookie = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($keys); $i++) { 
      $res_cookie .= $keys[$i];
      $res_cookie .= "=";
      $res_cookie .= $values[$i];
      if ($i < sizeof($keys) - 1) {
        $res_cookie .= "; ";
      }
    }
    curl_close($handle);
    // $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $next_url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $res_cookie);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    // curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    // curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

    $result = curl_exec($handle);
    echo $result;
```